# Android webview: highlight a specific word in a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, highlighting, android-webview

i am using a webview inside my android application. I would like to know if it is possible to highlight or underline a specific word/sentence/paragraph in a loaded page using code done in javascript?

thanks

Comment: yes, it's possible... what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [this page](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm). Do a view source.

They use pure Javascript--not even jQuery--to highlight particular words on the webpage.

Basically they load all of the text they want to search through into a variable and continuously find the `indexOf` the search term they want to highlight. When they find the index of the term, they build a new string with everything before that index + a `<span class="highlighted">` + the search term + `</span>`. Then they continue searching. Once they've searched and rebuilt all the text they replace the old text in the DOM with the new text.

They also have some CSS along the lines of `.highlighted { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: Oh wow, my mistake, I'm sorry I thought you were talking about a plain old webpage... I don't know if this is applicable to an "Android webview".

Comment: np, thx a lot man, this seems helpful, ill check if it works for webview and i'll let u know :)

Answer (score 15):

Why can't you try this? titleWebView is the WebView that has the html loaded or to be loaded. searchText should contain the text to be searched. I constructed a dialog to get the search terms from the user and reloaded the webpage each time the user hits the search. All the terms containing the searchText is highlighted (light green on my Nexus One). Hope this helps.

```
titleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (searchText != null && !searchText.equals("")) {
            int i = titleWebView.findAll(searchText);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found " + i + " results !",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.invoke(titleWebView, true);
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
            }
            searchText = "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you should reference to `WebView view` on `findAll(searchText)`. It should be the same (already fully loaded) webview just like the `titleWebView`.

Comment: Damn - I would give this 100 stars if i could - aswesome

Comment: Happy to help :)
I had trouble figuring it out the first time too. Android documentation helps.

Comment: I am getting a problem here. My text is highlighted but still the toast shows "Found 0 results!". I am not able to understand why?? Any string i may take, it highlights them properly but the findAll() method always returns 0. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I tried it with a couple of webviews and this always worked. Could you post some sample code?

Comment: its working.Reload the Webview every time when user hit the search button and paste the above code in webview.

Answer (score 2):

findAll() is deprecated! You can use findAllAsync() from API16 onwards in a simple manner like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (searchText != null && !searchText.equals("")) {
                    webView.findAllAsync(searchText);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
m.invoke(titleWebView, true);
```

After this test using following code.

```
findAll("search text")
```

When text is match `Toast` display.