# Can we have area selection feature on webview in android?

Tags: android, highlight, epub

We want to highlight webview text on any android device. But we want this highlight should save in the pages permanently. We are showing epub by using webview.

If anyone know about this, please guide us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we have tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294562/android-webview-highlight-a-specific-word-in-a-page-using-javascript. But it just highlight the search text we want to select & save the highlight permanently.

Comment: @Jyotsna have you tried for hightlight and got solution? i too using webview for displaying epub and need solution for highlight. If you got please share the information.

Answer (score 0):

> But we want this highlight should save in the pages permanently

Step #1: Maintain a database or file containing information about highlights (pages and what portions you highlighted)

Step #2: Apply the rules from the database or file from Step #1 whenever you display a page in the `WebView`

Comment: what model would you use to store the page & portion? a html file is comprised of many epub pages & font sizes can also change.

Comment: @sha256: I have no idea, as this isn't something I have worried about. My point, over three years ago when I wrote this answer, was that this is not somehow automatic with `WebView`. If you want this behavior, you will have to write it yourself.