# WebView.findAll doesnt find non-english characters

Tags: java, android, search, webview

I have a project which contains Html files, and I show them in a `WebView`, when the user try to search within the file, I use [WebView.findAll(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAll%28java.lang.String%29), it works fine on `English keywords`, but on `Arabic keywords` it allways return `0 (nothing found)` as result, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question I got it from: [Android webview: highlight a specific word in a page using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294562/android-webview-highlight-a-specific-word-in-a-page-using-javascript)

Tool: http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm (view source)

This is exactly what you want. I tested it with Arabic keywords and it worked. Good luck!

If you use this tool you have to enable Javascript on your webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: am looking for native solution without modifying the Html, i've tried this before and i know its working, and Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Apparently people are having issues finding English text too. This guy on Google groups had a solution not sure if it works not home atm. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/mkyho8_3ixo