# Use custom color to highlight searched text in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

After a lot of searching for documentation on how this can be done I am finally posting this on SO.

Currently in my app I have implemented a search feature to search text in webview. I am using the inbuilt webview methods to search and highlight all text entries, of the text searched by the user, in the webview.

I now want to change the default highlight color to my own custom color and not use the default implementation. I have been trying to look over everywhere for this but I did not see any specific way of how this can be done.

Can someone please give some hints/suggestions on how this can be done. Very thankful if you stopby and put some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do the trick for you:
http://danbarnett.net/how-to-hide-android-webview-highlight-border-or-change-its-color-142.html

From the sounds of it you can't actually change the default but you can work around it, or over-ride it using jquery and some css..

And some more Google results of interest:
http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/

And an overflow question with good answer:
[Android webview: highlight a specific word in a page using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294562/android-webview-highlight-a-specific-word-in-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Paul. The first option looks closer to me. My app has standalone webpages which I have created using twitter boot-strap. I think I will now have to figure out where to put in the web-kit thing in the css for twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I just checked the -webkit-tap-highlight-color CSS property and I believe it is for changing the text highlights for link taps on web page. My app just searches the user entered text in the entire webview and highlights all entries through a webview inbuilt function. I have to somehow override something in that function but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you able to put any code on here from the output of the webview window/area within your app?

If you can paste some source code I can definitely help - You must be able to do a view source on the output of a webview window under an emulator or something?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to get the view source of the webview on the emulator. For now I only have a snapshot of how it looks on the webview.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use the built in webview function for searching the text? I think a roll-your-own function would be better as you could replace each instance of text with your own and include any kind of css selector you wanted using a span tag, that would even allow hover actions and such - as well as in future if you wanted an on-click function..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not much of a html5/css3 guy. :( So to keep things simple and understandable for myself I kept it all to Android built in stuff.

Comment: There's no reason HTML, Javascipt and CSS can't be made simple - in fact, I'd say that if you were to use something like jQuery (don't panic about the name it's not that bad), you could achieve this task beautifully in less than an hour..
http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html - click the word highlight just after the heading 'Demo'

Comment: I should of added - you could easily then style those highlighted tags with colours, flashing GIF's, hover styles, flashing explosions of colour.. etc