# how to use custom color to highlight searched text in webview of android version 3.1

Tags: android, search, colors, webview, highlighting

I have a thinkpad tablet of android 3.1, I have an app using WebView, and search some keywords, but the searched text not highlight, how to change the default highlight color of findAll and findNext method of WebView? Very thankful if you stopby and put some of your thoughts.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461732/use-custom-color-to-highlight-searched-text-in-webview