# Use custom color for `findAllAsync` in android webview

Tags: android, webview

is there a way to give custom color for highlighting in webview's `findAllAsync` and `findAll` in android. I searched a lot a only received  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461732/use-custom-color-to-highlight-searched-text-in-webview)

but the when i looked in the reference in the answer provided i found out that the reference link is not working.

I know how to implement the same with JS/JQuery. But i want to do this with `findAllAsync` i searched a lot for this please help

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461732/use-custom-color-to-highlight-searched-text-in-webview